# 403 access denied on tomcat 7.0.42

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I am having error **403 access denied on tomcat 7.0.42** while accessing Tomcat Manager App.

This is what I have in *tomcat-user.xml* file.
I have tried changing roles over and over but did not work.

**Note: - I start/stop tomcat from NetBeans 7.3.1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: I think role should be manager-ui (assuming you are accessing manager app from browser_.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Remove the manager-script and add  "manager-gui,manager-status".

To access the HTML interface, you need to have the manager-gui role, but you must NOT have the manager-script or manager-jmx roles.

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-status"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

some information for you about roles from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

- manager-gui — Access to the HTML interface.
- manager-status — Access to the "Server Status" page only.
- manager-script — Access to the tools-friendly plain text interface that is described in this document, and to the "Server
  Status" page.
- manager-jmx — Access to JMX proxy interface and to the "Server Status" page.

Comment: You can have all the roles in the same user. From [http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html):

_If you use web browser to access the Manager application using a user that has either manager-script or manager-jmx roles (for example for testing the plain text or JMX interfaces), you MUST close all windows of the browser afterwards to terminate the session....

It is recommended to never grant the manager-script or manager-jmx roles to users that have the manager-gui role._

Comment: to me (using eclipse) did not work.   tomcat pisses me off >:(

Comment: The `manager-status` role is useless in the provided example, since it is implied by any of the remaining roles (cf. [application descriptor](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/402eb6bd2d9b3fafe434f858304898b51b9b85e4/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml#L140)).

Answer (score 1):

Though the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325762/13203493) is already the correct answer, I think maybe someone will be confused about the usage of "manager-script".

The "manager-script" is for accessing the Tomcat Manager API without using Web pages.

For instance, the command below is for requesting undeploy function instead of clicking the undeploy button on Tomcat Manager web app.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/manager/text/undeploy?path=/app_name
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not actually add the `tomcat` user to the `manager-script` role,

Answer (score 0):

I tied tomcat7 on ubuntu, and found that if you configure like this:

```
<user username="admin1" password="admin1" roles="manager-gui,manager-jmx,manager-script,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
<user username="admin2" password="admin2" roles="admin-gui,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-jmx,manager-script,manager-status"/>
```

admin1 will work OK, but admin2 will not have the access.
It seems that the order of the roles matters.

Answer (score -3):

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-status"/>
```

Add these to end of the tomcat-users.xml before  tag located inside conf folder.